# Breeze Web API Controller Method Name Convention

Tags: breeze

In [Official Docs](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller) about breeze and the Web API controller, we see some kind of naming convention for the method names on web Api controller. For example, for the Todo entity type, there is a Todos() method.

Suppose I have an entityType "Customer". Then I create a method on apiController:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers() { ... }
```

In my client javascript app, I run EntityQueries like that:

```
//api method: GetCustomers
//type name: Customer    

var query = EntityQuery.from("GetCustomers"); 
manager.execute(query); //works

manager.fetchEntityByKey("Customer", 53) //doesn't works!
```

It fails, I receive the folowwing error:

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI  
'http://localhost:4119/api/SomeController/Customers?$filter=Id eq 53'
```

So, Am I forced to rename my GetCustomers method to Customers() or Am I missing something ?

Comment: Does manager.fetchEntityByKey("GetCustomer", 53) work?

Comment: @Bryant no. it expects for a type name. Results on error saying cannot find a type by the name GetCustomer.

Comment: I'd probably say this issue is fairly simple. The convention is for the API method to be the plural of the entity name. If you want to name it something else then you're breaking the convention and would probably (a) need some kind of config or (b) have both GetCustomers and Customers.

Comment: I'm investigating if there is a way to config this convention. But what I'm guessing now is that probably there's some inconsistence between normal queries and fetchEntityByKey conventions.

Comment: Well a query != an entity. I have multiple queries from some entities, but the basic one always follows the entity name convention.

Comment: I think by default breeze discovers the name of the WebApi method for each EntityType from metadata (it looks for the EF DbSet name for that type). Try renaming your DbSet name from Customers to GetCustomers.

Comment: var newQuery = function (from, entityTypeName, predicateOrId) {
        var query = new entityModel.EntityQuery();
        if (from)
            query = query.from(from);
        if (entityTypeName)
            query.entityType = managerMeta.getEntityType(entityTypeName);
        if (predicateOrId) {
            if (predicateOrId instanceof breeze.Predicate) {
                query.wherePredicate = predicateOrId;
            } else {
                query = query.where("Id", breeze.FilterQueryOp.Equals, predicateOrId);
            }
        }
        return query;
    };

Comment: Alternatively create your breeze Query like this: 

var myQuery = newQuery('GetCustomers', 'Customer', 15);